# Was Howland Reed the Knight of the Laughing Tree?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *A Storm of Swords*, Jojen and Meera tell Bran the tale of the Knight of the Laughing Tree. They do not identify the Crannogman in the story, but both seem surprised that Eddard Stark has never told this story to Bran.

Is theCcrannogman in the story Howland Reed?  Is it ever identified if he (the Crannogman, whether or not it is Howland Reed) was truly the Knight of the Laughing Tree?

Comment: See http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Knight_of_the_Laughing_Tree for a summary of the story

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of the "players" of the story have ever been identified officially. Although it does seem obvious that the "Wolves" were the Starks, and it is heavily implied that the "Crannogman" was indeed Howland Reed, given Reed's strong loyalty to the Starks later on (actively joining them in their rebellion, and sending his two children to serve Winterfell). The "Mystery Knight" is a tougher nut to crack. Both Reed and Lyanna Stark have been put up as possible candidates. Both are small in stature, and both had a lot to prove. Personally, I'm leaning towards the Mystery Knight being Lyanna, who has a stronger case of needing to hide her identity in the lists. We also know (from flashbacks) that she was probably martially trained to some extent. OTOH Reed is a Crannogman, who are not exactly known for their equestrian skills.

Comment: +1. Identifying Lynna as the Mystery Knight fits a lot of other narrative elements together very nicely, particularly events with Rhaegar later on.

Answer (score 7):

I thought that the mystery knight was a young Ned Stark. He would have been in his early teens at that point and too young to sign up for the jousts properly.

After the mystery knight wins, the other knights offer to pay a ransom for the equipment (lances, some pieces of armor, etc) they lost to him. The mystery knight **in a booming voice**  tells them that teaching their squires about honor would be payment enough.

If it was Lyanna, the knights would have noticed the girl's voice. I think that it was either Ned or Howland.

Answer (score 5):

I had always believed that the Knight was actually Ned's sister Lyanna. I don't think there was much evidence to prove it.

At the relevant page on [Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Knight_of_the_Laughing_Tree), both the theories are mentioned but without any evidence to back them up.

Answer (score 2):

The Crannogman seems unarguably to have been Howland Reed but there are several arguments for him not being the Knight of the Laughing Tree. First of all he was offered the chance to compete by Benjen but declined. Secondly he had no experience of tourney jousting and only a fool would directly enter a highly public competition on their first attempt, without any practice. Thirdly why would he enter in secret anyway? He was an adult and fully entitled to take part. Mystery knights seem to have been either considered too young or were experienced champions who wanted to conceal their identities for some reason. Fourthly, Meera and Jojen seem surprised that Bran had not heard the story from his father, pressing the point repeatedly. If the Knight of the Laughing Tree had been Howland Reed then, apart from being a mildly amusing anecdote, why would it have been a big deal for Ned Stark?

Howland Reed was noted for his almost fanatical loyalty to Ned Stark later in life, surpassing even the loyalty expected of a bannerman. I would say the evidence therefore points to Ned Stark being the Laughing Knight, the Weirwood shield being entirely in keeping with his outlook. Being small of stature is easily explained by the fact that he was not yet grown to full adult height. His brother Brandon was a huge man (which rules him out incidentally) but Ned was more of average size. Ned also highly valued honour and respect and would have been motivated to teach the squires a lesson after the insult to his family's bannerman. I can't believe the Stark brothers would have allowed their sister to compete in their stead when it was a question of avenging family honour.