# Who were the characters in Meera Reed's story?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, character-identification

In Bran II from a Storm of Swords, Meera Reed tells a story about the Knight of the Laughing Tree. In this story, no names are mentioned, only descriptions of the characters. While it is already established that [the Crannogman is Howland Reed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6079/was-howland-reed-the-knight-of-the-laughing-tree), it is unclear to me who all of the other characters are.

The characters are:

- the King
- the dragon prince
- the White Swords

  - their new brother
- Storm lord
- Rose lord
- great lion of the rock (who wasn't there)
- daughter of the great castle
- her four brothers
- her uncle, a white knight of the Kingsguard
- A she-wolf
- A wild wolf
- A quiet wolf
- a pup
- Sworn swords of the wolves:

  - Barrowdown men
  - Moose
  - Bears
  - Mermen
- a man of the Night's Watch
- Knight of skulls and kisses
- a maid with laughing purple eyes
- a white sword (dancing with the maid above)
- a red snake
- the lord of griffins
- the pitchfork knight
- the porcupine knight
- the knight with two towers on his surcoat (already confirmed to be a Frey)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. the King - Aerys II Targaryen
2. the dragon prince - Rhaegar Targaryen
3. the White Swords - Kingsguards Ser Jonothor Darry, Ser Arthur Dayne, Ser Gerold Hightower (Lord Commander), Prince Lewyn Martell, Ser Barristan Selmy, Ser Oswell Whent
4. their new brother - Ser Jaime Lannister
5. Storm lord - Robert Baratheon
6. Rose lord - Lord Mace Tyrell
7. great lion of the rock (who wasn't there) - Lord Tywin Lannister
8. daughter of the great castle - Lord Walter Whent's daughter, blood of Harrenhal.
9. her four brothers - Lord Walter Whent's sons
10. her uncle, a white knight of the Kingsguard - Ser Oswell Whent
11. A she-wolf - Lyanna Stark
12. A wild wolf - Brandon Stark
13. A quiet wolf - Eddard Stark
14. a pup - Benjen Stark
15. Sworn swords of the wolves: Barrowdown men (Dustin levies), Moose (Hornwood men), Bears (Mormont Men), Mermen (Manderly men)
16. a man of the Night's Watch - No idea
17. Knight of skulls and kisses - Ser Richard Lonmouth
18. a maid with laughing purple eyes - Ashara Dayne
19. a white sword (dancing with the maid above) - Barristan Selmy
20. a red snake - Oberyn Martell
21. the lord of griffins - Jon Connington
22. the pitchfork knight - A knight of House Heigh
23. the porcupine knight - A Knight of House Blount
24. the knight with two towers on his surcoat (already confirmed to be a Frey) - A knight of House Frey

The passage itself:

> The [king](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aerys_II_Targaryen) himself was there, with his son [the dragon prince](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaegar_Targaryen). [The White
>   Swords had come](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kingsguard#Aerys_II_Targaryen_.28262_AC-283_AC.29), to welcome [a new brother](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaime_Lannister#Raised_to_Knighthood_and_to_the_Kingsguard) to their ranks. [The storm
>   lord](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robert_I_Baratheon) was on hand, and the [rose lord](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mace_Tyrell) as well. The [great lion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tywin_Lannister) of the
>   rock had quarreled with the king and stayed away, but many of his
>   bannermen and knights attended all the same.
>
> [...]
>
> “The [daughter of the great castle](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Walter_Whent#Family) reigned as queen of love and beauty
>   when the tourney opened. Five champions had sworn to defend her crown;
>   her [four brothers of Harrenhal](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Walter_Whent#Family), and [her famous uncle](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Oswell_Whent), a white knight
>   of the Kingsguard.”
>
> [...]
>
> The [she-wolf](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lyanna_Stark) laid into the squires with a tourney sword, scattering
>   them all. The crannogman was bruised and bloodied, so she took him
>   back to her lair to clean his cuts and bind them up with linen. There
>   he met her pack brothers: the [wild wolf](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brandon_Stark) who led them, [the quiet wolf](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Eddard_Stark)
>   beside him, and [the pup](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Benjen_Stark) who was youngest of the four.
>
> [...]
>
> he ate and drank with the wolves, and many of their sworn swords
>   besides, [barrowdown men](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Dustin) and [moose](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Hornwood) and [bears](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Mormont) and [mermen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Manderly). A black
>   brother spoke, asking the knights to join the Night’s Watch. The storm
>   lord drank down [the knight of skulls and kisses](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Richard_Lonmouth) in a wine-cup war. The
>   crannogman saw a [maid with laughing purple eyes](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ashara_Dayne) dance with [a white
>   sword](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Barristan_Selmy#In_the_Kingsguard), [a red snake](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Oberyn_Martell), and [the lord of griffins](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jon_Connington), and lastly with the
>   quiet wolf...
>
> [...]
>
> One served a [pitchfork knight](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Haigh), one a [porcupine](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Blount), while the last
>   attended [a knight with two towers on his surcoat](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Frey), a sigil all
>   crannogmen know well

Comment: I knew you'd come along and snake me... This is what I get for trying to have nice formatting, links and sources to start off with.

Comment: I think the man of the Night's Watch is [Yoren](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Yoren). His wiki page states he's been wondering crow for 30 years (though I haven't found a source for this) which places him as doing that during the event.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot possibly, but he wasn't the only Wandering Crow